# An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've seen this a million times, but my usual fixes and stackoverflow suggestions aren't working this time.

When I run `bundle install`, it fails at pg:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
```

In the past, I've solved this by first running `gem install bundler` before running `bundle install` again. This time, no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Most likely you need to first install postgresql to be able to install the gem on top. My current best approach to installing Postgresql on ubuntu: https://blog.corsego.com/ruby-on-rails-install-postgresql

Answer (score 14):

Of course, the moment I post this I find a fix on another stackoverflow question.

This did the trick:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: Thanks, this is important - there are two main ways to install Postgres on a Mac, one being through Homebrew (which most answers pertain to), and the other with Postgres.app, which this answer addresses. Thank you for adding your grain of sand & helping those like me that have the latter.

Answer (score 5):

face the same issue and I've solved this by first installing `brew install postgresql` and running `bundle install` again

Answer (score 4):

It's worth mentioning that you need to have Postgres installed on whatever machine you're trying to install the gem on for the gem to be installed.

It might be obvious to some, but not to others.

to verify that the actual problem is missing Postgres on the machine, the error should be somewhat similar to this:

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple of necessary system libraries. To install:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. For example, you haven’t elaborated that this will only work on Debian and Ubuntu versions of Linux.